# Which Google Apps Script API to enable the Document Service

Tags: google-apps-script

Folks, I've got a Google spreadsheet and contained Apps Script/JavaScript code project that works nicely.  Now I want to manipulate a Google document from that same code.  I open the document by its ID but when I try to write to it I get, "***Execution failed: Service unavailable: Docs***" in the Execution Transcript.  Is there a Google Documents API just like the Google Sheets API?  Seems that might be my solution but I can't find it.  How do I get access to the Docs Service?  Thanks.

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far (the code)

Comment: I found my problem. I'll comment in the Answer Your Question section.

Answer (score -1):

I found my problem. It wasn't related to a "Document Service API" at all. I was trying to write the wrong format data as text into the document.  I thought I could write an array.toString() but it turns out my array had subarrays, which were not toString()'d.  So just for completion, here are the simple document service pieces that I use to open and write to the doc:

```
  var doc  = DocumentApp.openById("1Ucq9dmuSztEk...fl0");
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var text = body.editAsText();
  var lines;
  // Build up a single huge string of lines, each line ended with a '\n' 
  // and then bang everything out in one shot. Results in a few pages of text.
  text.insertText(0, lines.toString());  // force as string
```

A piece of cake after I got my data right. Thx.